# TimeZoneInfo serialization issue c#

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, timezone

I had an issue serializing TimezoneInfo as it does not have a parameterless constructor.  I tried to get around it by doing what was suggested here

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a2bda890-41e9-47e8-b404-042d110e4f13/serializing-classes-containing-timezoneinfo?forum=netfxbcl

This is what my request object looks like

```
[MessageContract(WrapperNamespace = ServiceConstants.ContractNameSpaceMessageContract)]
public class GetTransactionsRequest
{
    [MessageHeader(Namespace = ServiceConstants.ContractNameSapceMessageHeader)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(Namespace = ServiceConstants.ContractNameSpaceMessageContract)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(Namespace = ServiceConstants.ContractNameSpaceMessageContract)]
    public string TimeZoneInfo
    {
        get { return tzInfo.ToSerializedString(); }
        set { tzInfo = System.TimeZoneInfo.FromSerializedString(value); }
    }

    private TimeZoneInfo tzInfo;
    public TimeZoneInfo TZInfo
    {
        get { return tzInfo; }
        internal set { tzInfo = value; }
    }

}
```

I have the following Contract interface

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(System.TimeZoneInfo))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(System.TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(System.TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule[]))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(System.TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(System.DayOfWeek))]

[ServiceContract(Name = "TransactionLobService", Namespace = ServiceConstants.ContractNameSpace)]
public interface ITransactionLobService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetTransactions")]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ExpenseAutomationFault))]
    GetTransactionsResponse GetTransactions(GetTransactionsRequest request);
}
```

I am consuming the service like so

```
    Dim client As TransactionLobService = New TransactionLobServiceClient()

    Dim getTransactionsRequest As New TransactionsLOBService.GetTransactionsRequest() With {
        .TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time").ToSerializedString(),
        .StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-03-27 00:00:00"),
        .EndDate = DateTime.Now
    }

    Dim response = client.GetTransactions(getTransactionsRequest)
```

I am still getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'GetTransactionsRequest'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot serialize member 'GetTransactionsRequest.TZInfo' of type 'System.TimeZoneInfo', see inner exception for more details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: System.TimeZoneInfo cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: I think it would be simpler to serialize the time zone ID instead of the whole TimeZoneInfo. There are some downsides to that in terms of knowing the rules at the time of serialization, but it would certainly be simpler.

Comment: I'm wondering if you really need to send timezone info separately. DateTimes can be unambiguous, with timezone information built in.

Comment: Can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the traceback, message, message type and inner exceptions (if any)?